# Change background of some holiday dates in Calendar control

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, calendar

I am using a basic calendar control in wpf desktop app and my requirement is to differentiate holidays (dates which are coming from mysql database) from regular dates by using c# language. My code is like :

```
<Calendar Name="MyCalendar"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="6"   Foreground="Aqua" SelectionMode="MultipleRange" SelectedDatesChanged="MyCalendar_SelectedDatesChanged" ></Calendar>
```

C# :

```
 private void MyCalendar_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listboxSelectedDates.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DateTime dr in MyCalendar.SelectedDates)
            {
                listboxSelectedDates.Items.Add(dr.ToShortDateString());
            }//add selected dates in list

          MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;database=newcompanydatabase;pwd=Admin@123;uid=root;");
            string q = "select _date from event_calendar;";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q,conn);
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if(MyCalendar.SelectedDate==rdr.GetDateTime(0))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("******* holiday");                    

                }
            }//if selected date is holiday, show occasion.

        }
```

How can I change back color of holidays using c#?

Comment: Do you want to stop user to select those dates?

Comment: No user can select them too..

Comment: @DipakAkhade Hi have you checked the answers ? Provide some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create one `DataTrigger` for every holiday.

```
<Style x:Key="cdbKey" TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
    <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Date}" Value="12/07/2015">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Turquoise"/>
          </DataTrigger>
          ... more such DataTriggers for every holiday
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But as holiday dates are stored in the database, so we need to add `DataTrigger` using code in a loop.

1. Define a `Style` targetting `CalenderDayButton`.

   ```
   <Style x:Key="cdbKey" TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
   ...                         
   </Style>
   ```
2. Set `CalendarDayButtonStyle` property

   `<Calendar ... CalendarDayButtonStyle="{StaticResource cdbKey}">`
3. Get your holiday dates from DB at proper place (window constructor etc).

   ```
   List<DateTime> holidaysDates = _getHolidayDatesFromDB();
   ```
4. Add `DataTriggers` using a loop for holiday dates list received in Step 3, using C# code and add them to the `Style` defined above.

   ```
           Style s = (Style)this.Resources["cdbKey"];

           /* Loop through the Dates retrieved from DataBase*/
             DateTime holidayDate = DateTime.Parse("10/02/2015");
             DataTrigger dataTrigger = new DataTrigger() { Binding = new Binding("Date"), Value = holidayDate };
             dataTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(CalendarDayButton.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.SandyBrown));
             s.Triggers.Add(dataTrigger);
           /*End Loop*/
   ```

   We have used `Binding("Date")` as our `Binding` property value in `DataTrigger`, this is because `CalenderDayButton` is having `DataContext` set automatically to a `DateTime` value.

I have changed `Background` of `CalenderDayButton` to SandyBrown, you can get fancier.

Comment: CalendarDayButton is generated automatically.

Comment: If I want same solution in ASP.net the what changes should be required? Because I need to convert WPF to ASP.net.

Comment: Ask this some asp.net guy. I have left Asp.net .

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve your goal, but I'll concentrate on one particular solution.

**Concept**

We shall define a helper class which will have two attached dependency properties, which we'll later attach to controls representing particular dates in `Calendar` control. These will be `Date` - identifying the date represented by the control, and `IsHoliday` - read-only property indicating whether the date (identified by `Date`) is a holiday or not. Then we'll set a trigger on each control which will change its background whenever `IsHoliday` is `true` for that control.

**Implementation**

First off, the helper class:

```
namespace MyHelpers
{
    public class HolidayHelper
    {
        public static DateTime GetDate(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (DateTime)obj.GetValue(DateProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDate(DependencyObject obj, DateTime value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(DateProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Date", typeof(DateTime), typeof(HolidayHelper), new PropertyMetadata { PropertyChangedCallback = DatePropertyChanged });

        private static void DatePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var date = GetDate(d);
            SetIsHoliday(d, CheckIsHoliday(date));
        }

        private static bool CheckIsHoliday(DateTime date)
        {
            //here we should determine whether 'date' is a holiday
            //or not and return corresponding value
        }

        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsHolidayPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("IsHoliday", typeof(bool), typeof(HolidayHelper), new PropertyMetadata());

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsHolidayProperty = IsHolidayPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

        public static bool GetIsHoliday(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsHolidayProperty);
        }

        private static void SetIsHoliday(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsHolidayPropertyKey, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever `Date` property is attached to any `DependencyObject` or it's value changes, the `IsHoliday` property will be updated accordingly.

Now a few useful facts:

- Each date in `Calendar` control is displayed by a `CalendarDayButton` control
- For each `CalendarDayButton` control the corresponding date is stored in its `DataContext` property
- One can customize the `CalendarDayButton` control for a particular `Calendar` by utilizing the `Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle` property

What we need to do is to bind `HolidayHelper.Date` property to `CalendarDayButton.DataContext`, and set a trigger on `HolidayHelper.IsHoliday` to update `CalendarDayButton.Background`:

```
<Calendar xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:MyHelpers">
    <Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
            <Setter Property="helpers:HolidayHelper.Date" Value="{Binding}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="helpers:HolidayHelper.IsHoliday" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="..." />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
</Calendar>
```

Comment: Error : The namespace prefix " local " is not defined. for calendar control. I don't know how to solve it...!!!

Comment: @DipakAkhade What you were missing was prefix definition and mapping to appropriate namespace. I've updated the example and changed the prefix to "helpers" and mapped it to `MyHelpers` namespace, so now it should work (note the namespace definition "around" the helper class). For more details on that see [XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms747086(v=vs.100).aspx).